# What are the pros/cons when defining an Endpoint as a URI over defining it programatically?

Tags: apache-camel

Consider the following:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
      FileEndpoint dropLocation = new FileEndpoint();
      dropLocation.setCamelContext(getContext());
      dropLocation.setFile(new File("/data"));
      dropLocation.setRecursive(true);
      dropLocation.setPreMove(".polled");
      dropLocation.setNoop(true);
      dropLocation.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);

      from(dropLocation).to(...
```

versus

```
public class MyBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("file://data?recursive=true&preMove=.polled&noop=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=1").to(...
```

Programatically I get code completion and the like, whereas with the URI everything is in a single line. Are these the only pros/cons or are there others to consider?

Pretty much all the examples I see utilise the URI method - is there a strong reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

generally you rely on the Component to create the Endpoint instance (via route definitions), but it can be done programmatically if there is a desire to integrate with legacy code, create Endpoints through class structures/instances, etc.

overall, a major benefit of Camel is to leverage it's concise DSL route capabilities to describe processes/interactions all in one place (a route).  the more programmatic the route definitions are, the more verbose/spread out these definitions become...

overall, I prefer the URI approach because its more concise, easier to follow and nice to manipulate route parameters all in one place...otherwise, its entirely a preference/style decision.